# .htaccess is not working on aws ec2 multi domain hosted

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

.htaccess isn't working on my server. I'm hosting 2 domains on that server.
I installed phpmyadmin using-> [Secure phpmyadmin](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04).

.htaccess for serverip/phpmyadmin/ is working fine but not for the other domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Solved !!
I added few lines of code in VirtualHost just below the Document Root-

VirtualHost File Located in my case was -
`/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`

Added Below -

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

I added -

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

I repeated same with my other domain VirtualHost File.

Then Apache2 Restart - `sudo service apache2 restart`

I hope this helps to people :)